# Display all post meta keys and meta values of the same post ID in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display post meta values and post meta keys, If only one value is to be display I can used the simple function get_post_meta() but what I need now is to post all post meta data with the same post_id. I tried using foreach loop but nothing displays. Can you please check my code?

```
function wpt_calendar_display()
{
    global $post;

    $columns = array(
        'date_event' => 'Date',
        'name_event' => 'Event'
    );
    register_column_headers('list-header_events', $columns);

    $event_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_event_name' );
   // $event_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_event_date', false );

    $return .= "<table class=\"widefat\">";
    $return .= "<tr>";
    $return .= print_column_headers('list-header_events');
    $return .= "</tr>";
    $return .= "<tr>";

    if (!empty($event_name))
    foreach($event_name as $e_name)
    {
        $return .= "<td>";
        $return .= $e_name;
        $return .="</td>";
      
    }

    $return .= "<td>";
    
    $return .= "</td>";
    $return .= "</tr>";
    $return .= "</table>";
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I wrote an article to explain it better way. if you are interested read it here at http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/06/get_post_meta-example/

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> Default Usage
>
> Get the meta for all keys:

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta($post_id); ?>
```

> Get the meta for a single key:

```
<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta( 76, 'key_1' ); ?>
```

for example:

```
$myvals = get_post_meta($post_id);

foreach($myvals as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key . ' : ' . $val[0] . '<br/>';
}
```

> **Note: some unwanted meta keys starting with "underscore(_)" will also come, so you will need to filter them out.**

For reference: [See Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Default_Usage)

Comment: I'm trying to get all same post id and same meta key. I already know how to get single key. thanks

Comment: just pass post_id without any key.... in `get_post_meta` method as i hav mentioned

Comment: when I do that it display the word Array

Comment: I tested this one. If I used this $getdata = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_event_name'); No output is generating.. But when I changed the $post->ID to specific ID of the post. It is displaying the correct output. hmm..

Comment: see my updated answer and accept answer if it helps u.

Comment: I tried changing it to this..  $myvals = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_event_name'); It generates no output. :(

Comment: why are u putting another paramerter just use ..... `$myvals = get_post_meta($post->ID)`

Comment: my bad,. I simply don't have a meta values for that part thats why no outputs. I'm over thinking, making me miss the simple part. Thanks mate

Answer (score 10):

To get all rows, don't specify the key. Try this:

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );

var_dump( $meta_values );
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

As of Jan 2020 and WordPress v5.3.2, I confirm the following works fine.

<s>It will include the field keys with their equivalent underscore keys as well, but I guess if you properly "enum" your keys in your code, that should be no problem:</s>

```
$meta_values   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
$example_field = meta_values['example_field_key'][0];

//OR if you do enum style 
//(emulation of a class with a list of *const* as enum does not exist in PHP per se)
$example_field = meta_values[PostTypeEnum::FIELD_EXAMPLE_KEY][0];
```

As the `print_r(meta_values);` gives:

```
Array
(
    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1579542560:1
        )

    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [example_field] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
        )
)
```

Hope that helps someone, go make a ruckus!

Answer (score 2):

```
$myvals = get_post_meta( get_the_ID());
foreach($myvals as $key=>$val){
  foreach($val as $vals){
    if ($key=='Youtube'){
       echo $vals 
    }
   }
 }
```

Key = Youtube videos all meta keys for youtube videos and value

Answer (score 1):

I use it in form of a meta box. Here is a function that dumps values of all the meta data for post.

```
    function dump_all_meta(){

        echo "<h3>All Post Meta</h3>";

        // Get all the data.
        $getPostCustom=get_post_custom();


        foreach( $getPostCustom as $name=>$value ) {

            echo "<strong>".$name."</strong>"."  =>  ";

            foreach($getPostCustom as $name=>$value) {

        echo "<strong>".$name."</strong>"."  =>  ";

        foreach($value as $nameAr=>$valueAr) {
                echo "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo $nameAr."  =>  ";
                echo var_dump($valueAr);
        }

        echo "<br /><br />";

        }
    } // Callback funtion ended.
```

Hope it helps. You can use it inside a meta box or at the front-end.

Comment: This was helpful... however, I had to remove the two repeated code lines that were cause for an exception... FYI, these lines are repeated & should be removed:  
  
 foreach($getPostCustom as $name=>$value) {
 echo "<strong>".$name."</strong>"."  =>  ";

Comment: ^That is coz of you particular condition I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This code showed me all the meta keys and value pairs and then saw the values that some meta values contain arrays within arrays. which is why I wasn't getting the yith value I was trying to obtain. I just noticed your question was about wordpress posts, and my answer is about woocommerce order meta data. google brought me here when asking about woocommerce order meta data, so the answer I will leave here anyway.

```
<?php
// Load WordPress functionality
require_once('wp-load.php');

$order_id = intval('123949');
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

if ($order) {
    echo "Order found.<br/>";

    // Initialize an array to hold simplified item meta data for JSON encoding
    $simplified_item_meta_data = array();
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        echo "Processing Order Item ID: $item_id, Product Name: " . $item->get_name() . "<br/>"; // Debug

        // Each item's meta data will be stored under its item ID key in the simplified array
        $simplified_item_meta_data[$item_id] = array();

        // Extract and simplify the meta data for the item
        foreach ($item->get_meta_data() as $meta) {
            $simplified_item_meta_data[$item_id][$meta->key] = $meta->value;
            echo "Meta Key: " . $meta->key . ", Value: " . $meta->value . "<br/>"; // Debug
        }
    }

    if(empty($simplified_item_meta_data)) {
        echo "No simplified item meta data found.<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Simplified item meta data found.<br/>";
        // Continue with your logic here...
    }

    // Ensure you can see the collected and simplified item meta data
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($simplified_item_meta_data, true) . "</pre>";

    // Now, you can proceed with the rest of your script logic,
    // utilizing the correctly populated $simplified_item_meta_data

} else {
    echo "Order not found.<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

WordPress have the function [get_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata) this get all meta of object (Post, term, user...)

Just use

```
get_metadata( 'post', 15 );
```

Comment: This does not get custom post meta.  It only retrieves WP default meta data.