# How to get post meta from another database in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to get the custom fields from a database external to my wordpress; I can get the posts but I don't know how to get their respective post meta.

```
function seconddb() {
    global $seconddb;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 
                  'show_posts' => '10', 
                  'paged' => $paged
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); 
    $seconddb = new wpdb('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
    $rows = $seconddb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM K1nG_posts");
    foreach ($rows as $obj) :
        echo $obj->ID;
        endforeach;

    // Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post', true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'seconddb');
```

Can anyone help me obtain the respective custom fields found post_meta in db of Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this SO and codex.wordpress link could be of help in resolving your problem

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_meta_Function_Examples

[Display all post meta keys and meta values of the same post ID in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216276/display-all-post-meta-keys-and-meta-values-of-the-same-post-id-in-wordpress)